# Else if statement not functioning when given a condition

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter price in cents:");
        int money = 100;
        int itemPrice = scan.nextInt();
        money = money - itemPrice;
        int quarter = money / 25;
        money = money % 25;
        int dime = money / 10;
        money = money % 10;
        int nickel = money / 5;
        money = money % 5;

        if (itemPrice < 25 || itemPrice > 100) {
            System.out.println("Invalid price!");
            return;
        } else if ((itemPrice % 5 == 1)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid price!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Your change is " + quarter + " quarters, " + dime + " dimes, and " + nickel + " nickels.");
    }
}
```

This is my code, whenever I try to get the else if statement to run, it doesnt.  So if I were to enter 54, it would still make the change and not print out "Invalid Price"!

Comment: 54 % 5 is 4. What are you trying to test for?

Comment: `54 % 5 = 4` and not `1`. Debug and see it for yourself.

Comment: @tkausl Basically im trying to make it so that if it isnt divisible by 5 then its an invalid value.  I meant to say since 54 isnt divisble 5, its an invalid output, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `itemPrice%5!=0` instead of `itemPrice%5==1`, if you want to check that `itemPrice` is not divisible by 5.

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense, sorry I am just now beginning to learn Java!